# split mydumper sql file into separate sql files

Tags: sql, perl, unix, awk

I am trying to split a file created by mydumper into a single for each SQL statement. The ending delimiter is ; but it is multiline.

I thought I had it with this command line:

```
/bin/awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"}{x="export."++i;}{print $0";"> x".sql";}'
```

but the resulting files are not terminated properly. My samples that were much fewer lines worked fine. So my question is, how do I split the SQL file with complete lines?

In my sample files I had this sql repeated and everything worked fine.

```
insert into table (field) values
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('asdf'),
    ('end');
```

Does awk have some sort of record length limit?

```
[root@db294 TEST]# wc -l *.sql
10364 export.66.sql
10304 export.67.sql
10209 export.68.sql
10208 export.69.sql
10582 export.6.sql
10207 export.70.sql
10207 export.71.sql
 9979 export.72.sql
 9918 export.73.sql
 9918 export.74.sql
 9926 export.75.sql
 9931 export.76.sql
10061 export.77.sql
10225 export.78.sql
10209 export.79.sql
10585 export.7.sql
```

Maybe it's time to reopen my Camel book and try Perl vs Awk

Someone please create the tag for mydumper as I don't have 1500 points to create a tag.

Comment: I can't verify this so I won't put it as a answer, but I would try closing the previous file before writing to the new one. Maybe it's an issue of having too many files open. `awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"}{ close("export" i ".sql"); ...`

Comment: Put it in a answer and I'll accept it. That was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Camel book can stay on the shelf for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely a problem of having too many files open. Try closing the previous file before writing to the next one.

```
/bin/awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"}{close("export" i ".sql"); x="export."++i;} {print $0";"> x".sql";}'
```

Answer (score 1):

TIMTOWTDI. One could be:

```
perl -0x3b -MPath::Tiny -nE 'path("export.@{[++$n]}.sql")->spew($_)'
```